# Google Map API 2 localization problems

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, localization

How can I change language used on map buttons and terms of use ? I am using Google Maps API 2 (to be exact ASP.NET [GoogleMap](http://googlemap.codeplex.com/) control v4.1)
Does this depends from browser language. I can see on some sites that this text is localized and can't find any way to do that.

Here is the screenshot of text that I would like to localize:

[image]

Comment: consider upgrading to V3 of the Google Maps API, since V2 is deprecated

Comment: @Matt maybe you was to fast :) I see screenshot OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the hl-parameter when including the gMap2-library

e.g: force croatian to be used as language:(`hl=hr`)

```
<script 
 src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=hr&file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=yourKey"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

When using V3 the parameter-name will be **language** instead of **hl**